# Click through sections vertically using a fixed side bar menu

Tags: jquery, html

I have a one-paged website that is separated into sections. I have two arrows, one up and one down, that on click should scroll to either the next or previous section. The arrows are fixed elements.

Any pointers as to why it's not working would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

JQUERY

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.extend({
scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {
return this.each(function() {
  var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
});
}
});

$('.next-section').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this),
    $next = $this.parent().next();

$next.scrollTo(400, 'linear');
});

$('.prev-section').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this),
    $prev = $this.parent().prev();

$prev.scrollTo(400, 'linear');
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="arrowmenu">
<a href="#" class="prev-section"><img src="../images/up.png"></a><br>
<a href="#" class="next-section"><img src="../images/down.png"></a><br>
</div>
```

AND MY SECTIONS ARE DIVIDED LIKE SO:

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
Content...
</div>
```

Comment: What, exactly is the issue. Maybe you could set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: yes you show you issue by directly give your site link or make a fiddle

Comment: I've uploaded the website here: http://karenrubkiewicz.com/portfolio